# Selenium Python webscraping 'Nonetype object' has no attribute 'div'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web scraping. I'm trying to use beautiful soup and selenium to scrape numbers off a dynamically loaded website.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://roobet.com/crash')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features="html5lib")
crash = soup.find('div', class_='CrashHistory_2YtPR')
num = crash.div.text
num.replace('x','')
print(num)
```

when I run this using ''' python testcrash.py ''' in command prompt I get.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:7628/devtools/browser/fb52b5de-1423-488a-a4dd-8442deff01d2
[34012:34760:0423/201837.291:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testcrash.py", line 10, in <module>
    num = crash.div.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'div'
```

but when I run the code line by line in python application I get what I need. this is what it looks like

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> import bs4
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> driver=webdriver.Chrome()

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:4917/devtools/browser/887f1d53-d7d1-4a56-929b-bf46e13cff9d
[8592:31756:0423/171506.777:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
>>>
>>> driver.get('https://roobet.com/crash')
>>> html = driver.page_source
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features="html5lib")
>>> crash = soup.find('div', class_='CrashHistory_2YtPR')
>>> num = crash.div.text
>>> num
'2.38x'
>>>
```

heres a screen shot of the page and object I'm trying to scrape:

[image]

Comment: Why use both Selenium **and** BeautifulSoup? Can you provide a [mcve]? As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @AMC I updated the code example to a minimal reproducible example. I'm using Selenium and BeautifulSoup because earlier I tried using BeautifulSoup by itself but it could not find the 'CrashHistory_2YtPR' class. I made another post about it and someone said that it was because the site was dynamically loaded, and to try using selenium and ChromeDriver. I did a quick test using selenium, and it worked. I could print out text from objects inside the  'CrashHistory_2YtPR' class.

Comment: I solved the problem. I just needed to put a ```time.sleep(2)``` after ```driver.get('https://roobet.com/crash')```

Comment: Yes, in which case you would use just Selenium, no?

Comment: _I made another post about it and someone said that it was because the site was dynamically loaded_ I just checked, it turns out that person was me lol

Comment: @AMC Im not sure. I don't even know what selenium is or what it does. I just needed to learn how to make a simple webscraper quickly to see if I could make some money on a gambling website. I didn't know how to webscrape without using beautiful soup. I just searched how to webscrape using python into youtube and the first video used beautiful soup.  Anyways I solved the problem, thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, well there are plenty of resources on web scraping and Selenium, don’t worry!